# Maven: How to run some tests after the "install" phase, during a "release:prepare"?

Tags: java, maven

I have some complex tests that use *standalone Maven projects* to validate some code. Those Maven projects are programatically packaged by the tests and the resulting `.jar` files are then used. Those projects use artifacts from my main multi-modules project *at the current version*, in their `pom.xml`. In other words, the test Maven projects need to be able to find artifacts provided by my main project.

In an IDE, everything works fine since the current artifacts from my main project are resolved dynamically (no local repository required) when I run the tests. Also, I can install those SNAPSHOT versions before running the tests. But when I want to release a new version of my project, I would need `release:prepare` to:

- Update the versions (remove all the "-SNAPSHOT").
- Runs all tests that do not end with `*.PostInstallTest.java`.
- Package the artifacts and *install them* locally.
- THEN runs the tests that end with `*.PostInstallTest.java`, since those tests require access to the previously installed artifacts! If the tests fail, no commits would by pushed by `release:prepare`.

I know this is not perfect since a "bad" version of the artifacts could be installed locally, when the "PostInstallTest" tests fail. But I would prefere that to not having those tests run at all!

Currently, my only working idea is to set an system property when the `release` profile is used, and have the `*.PostInstallTest.java` files disable themselves if that property exists. That way, those tests would still work when ran inside my IDE (without the `release` profile), but wouldn't be executed at all during a `release:prepare` command. But, again, I would like them to be executed.

I looked at the [preparationGoals](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/run-goals-before-commit.html) configuration of the Maven Release Plugin but I'm not sure how it could help me. I also looked at the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) but it doesn't seem to support the "install" phase.

**So, my question**: Is there a way to run some tests *after* the "install" phase, when `release:prepare` is used (or *at* the "install" phase, but after the default plugin)?

UPDATE: Here's a quick schema, if it can help understand what's going on:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: I didn't test Failsafe properly, after all. It does work at the "install" phase! Look at df778899's answer.

Comment: Would additional command before mvn release:prepare be acceptable?

Comment: I guess this may be a solution, indeed! I would prefere if something was possible without that, though.

Comment: @Lesiak What command would you suggest? Because the tests are also ran by `release:prepare` *after* all the `-SNAPSHOT` have been removed from the versions of my maina rtifacts... How could I install those non snapshot versions prior to running `release:prepare` so the non snapshot tests can find them?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem now. Have you tried moving failsafe plugin to the install phase? Failsafe plugin has a default phase, but it can be overridden for each execution with <phase> tag. Maven executes plugins for each phase in order they are defined in pom. Maybe you will have to explicitly include maven-install-plugin to force order in the install phase

Comment: As I say in my description, I did try using Failsafe at the "install" phase, but it doesn't want... :-(

Comment: Can the modules see the other modules they need as part of the Maven build (in other words are they modules somewhere in the chain of parent poms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an answer as yet, but to expand on @Lesiak's point, the Failsafe plugin looks fine by itself in the install phase.  For example:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Results in this output:

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ it-test ---
[INFO] Installing ...\target\it-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to ...\.m2\repository\group\it-test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\it-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing ...\pom.xml to ...\.m2\repository\group\it-test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\it-test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M3:integration-test (default) @ it-test ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TheIT
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.093 s - in TheIT
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M3:verify (default) @ it-test ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Note how the `maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M3:integration-test` and `maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M3:verify` goals are run at the end - in the `install` phase.

Comment: The "verify" phase is *before* the "install" phase : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html . The failsafe plugin doesn't support the "install" phase, an error is thrown.

Comment: As you say, by default the `verify` goal in the Failsafe plugin would normally run in the `verify` phase of the Maven lifecycle.  Setting `<phase>install</phase>` against the Failsafe plugin should move the `verify` goal (and the `integration-test` goal for that matter) to the `install` phase.  I've updated the answer to hopefully make this clearer.  Can you expand on the error that's being thrown?

Comment: I stand corrected. Failsafe *does* work properly on the "install" phase! I think I tested with something stupid, such as `<role>install</role>` instead of `<phase>install</phase>`. I'll still leave my question in case it helps someone in the future. Enjoy your bounty and a big thanks from me!

Answer (score 2):

Check the following setup.
It relies on `preparationGoals` to execute install.
In the configuration of the failsafe plugin, I configured it to run in the install phase.

I believe variations of this approach will work fine as well - you can try unbinding failsafe from any phase (phase set to None), and call it explicitely in `preparationGoals` (probably this needs some extra config like execution id, but I think you can continue from this point).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <preparationGoals>clean verify install</preparationGoals>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <!-- Specify the version of maven-scm-plugin to avoid https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-682
                    (Maven release fails when releasing from a named branch)
                    -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The output (edited a bit to reduce noise) shows that the verify taks launched by `preparationGoals` are executed after install.

```
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) @ demo ---
...
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
What is the release version for "demo"? (com.example:demo) 0.0.1: :
What is SCM release tag or label for "demo"? (com.example:demo) demo-0.0.1: :
What is the new development version for "demo"? (com.example:demo) 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT: :
[INFO] Transforming 'demo'...
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify install'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------< com.example:demo >--------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building demo 0.0.1
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1:jar (default-jar) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.1:jar (default-jar) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: demo-0.0.1.jar

[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] Installing demo-0.0.1.jar to 

[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.1:integration-test (default) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.22.1:verify (default) @ demo ---
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 13.784 s

[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
```